# How to set a custom palette for a Google Chart, with fixed color for each Line/Bar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, charts

I'm trying to use a custom palette for a Google Chart instance, within Google Apps Script code.
The problem is that, turning off a line and redrawing, the chart reassigns colors to the graph lines, misleading users (imho: if I turn off the first line, the second gets its color, giving the impression that the line was not set off and values changed).

I'd like to have a fixed color for each line, without colors shifting from one line to another.

I'm using a DataView to control chart display, built using a DataTable, like this:

```
publishersData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
publisherSeries = []:

// then, looping over columns...
  publisherSeries[i] = {
   'type':'line',
   'tooltip':<true or false>,
   'visible':<true or false>,
   'color':CustomPalette[i]
  }
  // if a column should initially not appear, lets add it to a control list
  if (<column should be hidden>) {
   hiddenCols.push(i);
  }
// loop ends
...
// Series data go into chart's options
chartOptions = {
 'title':'',
 'focusTarget':'category',
 'seriesType':'line',
 'width':'800',
 'height':'300',
 'series':publishersSeries,
 'legend':'none'
};
...
// create a chart
let chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartCode);
// create a DataView
let newDataView = new google.visualization.DataView(publishersData);
// hide columns
newDataView.hideColumns(hiddenCols);
// draw chart
chart.draw(newDataView, chartOptions);
```

This works fine, I get my chart with lines of the color I want.
Beside my chart, I've buttons (and no legend) to turn lines on or off.
When a button is clicked, I repeat the same process: get the chart, create a DataView, set visibility and tooltip according to button status, reassign color to each line and hide unwanted columns. Finally redraw the chart.

It works fine and I'd expect the chart to keep my color's settings, colors are shifted instead: if I turn off a line at any position, the colors of the following lines are all shifted.
How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks for any suggestion!
F.